# Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF is not working all time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to check how long user have kept screen on. I am using broadcast receiver Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT and Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF to calculate duration. Most of the time code working well but sometimes I am getting wrong.

```
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        //screen off sequence=0
    } else if ((intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT))) {
        //user is present sequence=2
    } else if ((intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))) {
        //locked screen present but not unlocked yet sequence=1
    }
}
```

Here is my error case. Between 3 and 4 there should be sequence=0 but missed.

**Is there any reason to miss screen goes off from above the code?**

1. sequence=0 //screen goes off
2. sequence=1 //lock screen present
3. sequence=2 //user present
4. sequence=1 //lock screen present
5. sequence=2 //user present

Comment: "Between 3 and 4 there should be sequence=0 but missed" -- technically, I do not think that this is required, as device admin APIs might cause the lock screen to appear even without the screen having turned off. In general, I am skeptical that you will be able to get reliable results using broadcasts as a driver of a state machine like this, because your process may not be running at the time the broadcasts are sent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I am writing to database from broadcastreceiver class. suppose like    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        //insert value in database
    }  how to make sure that every time my process will run or is there any  other way to get screen off every time?

Comment: "how to make sure that every time my process will run" -- build your own custom ROM and implement this as part of some Linux daemon that you run via `init.rc`, then convince people to install that custom ROM on their devices. At the Android SDK level, processes get terminated all the time, even if you have a service running. Using a foreground service minimizes the odds that your process will be terminated, but it still may not last forever. "is there any other way to get screen off every time?" -- not that I am aware of, in terms of ordinary Android SDK apps.